# creating android AVD with older OS

Tags: android, target, android-virtual-device

Im trying to create a Virtual Device to test Froyo 2 OS,
but when creating an emulator AVD the lowest Target that is available is 4.2.2

I have the min sdk set to 8 in the project manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

How to test older OSs with the emulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but when creating an emulator AVD the lowest Target that is available is 4.2.2

Then you need to download the others from the SDK Manager:

[image: Android SDK Manager]

Depending on the API level/OS version, you will see:

- ARM EABI v7a System Image
- Intel x86 Atom System Image (for use with the accelerated emulator)
- MIPS System Image (not typically useful)
- SDK Platform (which includes ARM system images, for Android through Android 3.2)

Download what you want, and they will appear as options for you in your AVD Manager.